# How Aspose PDF finds the License Object

Tags: c#, aspose

The question is generic and not related specifically to Aspose product but it will help me to explain the question better.

Aspose has two seperated classes:

```
namespace Aspose.Cells
{
    public class License
    {
        public License();

        public void SetLicense(string licenseName);
        public void SetLicense(Stream stream);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Workbook : IDisposable
{
        public Workbook();
        public Workbook(FileFormatType fileFormatType);
        public Workbook(string file);
        public Workbook(Stream stream);
        public Workbook(string file, LoadOptions loadOptions);
        public Workbook(Stream stream, LoadOptions loadOptions);

        public WorksheetCollection Worksheets { get; }
        public bool IsLicensed { get; }
}
```

As per the documentation of the aspose, i need to set a licence key using the following lines *one time per application*:

```
Aspose.Cells.License licence = new License();
licence .SetLicense("License file.txt");
```

And then, i can use the following workbook class without the need to set the license again.

```
 Workbook workbook = new Workbook(stream, new LoadOptions(loadFormat));
 Console.WriteLine(workbook.IsLicensed);
```

Everything is working perfect but i would like to understand who the workbook object access the licence object without passing the licence object as a reference to the workbook? What is the trick? It looks like the workbook object can access the licence object directly...

Comment: Probably just a static property.

Comment: @DavidG how can i access on runtime to a static property without reference?

Comment: Do you know what `static` means?

Comment: @DavidG - Sure, but as you can see in the example i can  instantiate both of the classes...

Comment: @Omtechguy - By definition, Static objects don't have references.  They're global.

Comment: @DavidG Oh... i think i got you... they are communicating via third static class "behind the science"?

Comment: @Omtechguy - Or something similar (maybe it's locking some physical memory, or doing something else to create global data).

Comment: Maybe a third class, but you can have a static property on a non-static class. Who knows. This question isn't really on-topic here as it's dealing with internal implementation of another library.

Comment: It's not an answer though, it's just one possibility. That's why the question is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

License is a library level property which is accessible to all the members of the library for verification. When a library is loaded once in the application and a license is initialized, then there is no need to initialize the license again. Either multithreading is used or any other architecture is implemented, one time license initialization is sufficient and all the members of the library like Workbook and others have access to it.

You may please visit following link for more details on licensing using Aspose.Cells.

https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Licensing

Note: I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: What does it mean "library level property" ? I see here two separated classes... Can you share an example of a "link" between two classes like this?

Comment: Thanks to @DavidG and Erik Funkenbusch i understood that "library level property" is a static property and now the answer is clear. Thank you all!